# Serving images in 2x dpr ruins lighthouse score

Tags: html, reactjs, optimization, lighthouse

#### Setup:

So I'm trying to optimize my image loads, while also not compromising on performance. I am using a react component that automatically finds the correct image sizes for the device's dpr and the image's width.

The images are divided into 3 types of sizes, computer, mobile, table. I manually determined the best aspect ratio of each image. So, if the image is rendered as 400x1000, the 1x dpr version would be 400x1000, and the 2x dpr version would be 800x2000. Based on the dpr and width, a certain image would be used.

#### Problem:

My score on lighthouse gets lowered if I use the 2x dpr images, even though those are the correct image sizes. If I switch to only using 1x dpr images, lighthouse does not lower my score, but the images are not good quality.

Here is the code for my image component

```
<picture style={{ display: "contents" }}>
  // COMPUTER (shown if width > 800px)
  <source
    srcSet={`${name}-computer-1x.${ext} 1x, ${name}-computer-2x.${ext} 2x`}
    media="(min-width: 800px)"
  />
  // TABLET (shown if width > 400px and < 800px)
  <source
    srcSet={`${name}-tablet-1x.${ext} 1x, ${name}-tablet-2x.${ext} 2x`}
    media="(min-width: 400px)"
  />
  // MOBILE (shown if width < 400px)
  <source
    srcSet={`${name}-mobile-1x.${ext} 1x, ${name}-mobile-2x.${ext} 2x`}
  />
  // FALLBACK (Older browsers)
  <img
    src={src}
    alt={alt}
    fetchpriority={priority ? "high" : "auto"}
    {...otherProps}
    ref={ref}
  />
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

Optimize for the user, not for Lighthouse. Removing all the content completely would also lead to a faster website.

[PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/) shows what real users are experiencing at the top, followed by a Lighthouse audit beneath. If the real users are happy that's what matters.

Saying that, it's very possible to achieve high Lighthouse scores while using 2x images. So it seems odd it's having such an impact on the score to ruin it. If your 2x images are absolutely huge, then it will slow the website down. Can they be optimised at all, while still retaining the 2x pixel ratio?

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. Lighthouse tests mobile using a moto G Power dimension with 1.8x dpr. This makes my images use the 2x dpr image. However, it also has a width of around 412-425px. Therefore, it uses my tablet images instead of the mobile ones. What's weird, is that when I make the media queries for table a minimum of 500px, it still does not fix the issue.